# Simple Asp .Net Application, error : Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, asmx

Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
**Description**: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. *Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.8689; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.8670*

Configuration: .Net framework 3.5, windows 10 operating system [IIS express 10]

How can I solve this Problem, Please help me

Comment: Most likely... The file pointed to by that url is missing (replace it), or the permissions on the file are wrong (fix them - remember it's the App pool user that needs read permission) or the server requires a file to process the request and it's unavailable. To find out exactly what the problem is, connect to the server and browse to that page locally (eg instead of browsing to `http://example.com/some/url`, connect to the `example.com` server and browse to `http://localhost/some/url`). That should show you more error information.

Comment: You have to dig into the source code to see why it returns 404 error response in this case. The page comes from ASP.NET based on your description (though you should paste the screen shot to confirm), so it does not mean that "IIS cannot find the file".

Comment: The error message is saying your version of .NET is 2, but you say IIS is configured with 3.5 - if there's a discrepancy here, it could be causing the issue.  What version of .NET is your application expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Hosting server will typically generate a "`404 Not Found`" web page when a user attempts to follow a broken or dead link.

Check the URL and look for resource (webpage/service/view) does exist?

Answer (score -1):

This means that the url you tried to access doesnt exist, or the IIS is not running, are you sure you ran it from visual studio using F5 ?